# Can't see other meta sites than meta.SO in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

When posting a question to a Stack Exchange site, you can only choose Meta Stack Overflow and not any of the other Meta sites (Meta Android, etc.):

[image]

Similarly, you can't view any of the other Meta sites either:

[image]

It would be nice to view site specific Meta sites too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely; just one of the many things that we didn't get to before the first alpha push. Version 0.1.1 will add Meta sites to the site list:

[image: screenshot of the spinner allowing to show meta sites]

Asking questions on child metas was a bit trickier; that will be in version 0.1.2.